# Two objects with same address not equal (==)

Tags: java, identity

I have a property and a method both of type `Team`:
`this.team` and `flag.getTeam()` (which is just a single-lined getter of that property).

Here are the respective `toString()` outputs:
`org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.scoreboard.CraftTeam@674e0730`
and `org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_12_R1.scoreboard.CraftTeam@674e0730`

`team == flag.getTeam()` returns `false`, while
`team.hashCode() == flag.getTeam().hashCode()` returns `true` and
`team.toString().equals(flag.getTeam().toString())` returns `true`

```
public class PlayerTimer extends BukkitRunnable {

    Domination plugin;
    Player player;
    Team team;
    public PlayerTimer(Domination plugin, Player player) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        this.player = player;
        for (Team team : plugin.getWorldGameScoreboards().get(plugin.getCurrentWorld()).getTeams()) {
            for (OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer : team.getPlayers()) {
                if (offlinePlayer.getPlayer() == player) {
                    this.team = team;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (this.team != null) break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (Flag flag : plugin.getWorldFlags().get(plugin.getCurrentWorld())) {
            for (OfflinePlayer offlinePlayer : team.getPlayers()) {
                if (offlinePlayer.isOnline()) {
                    Player player = offlinePlayer.getPlayer();
                    double scaledDistance = player.getLocation().distance(flag.getLocation()) / 5;  // max 5 blocks away
                    if (scaledDistance < 1) {
                        plugin.log(team + " : " + flag.getTeam() + ", " + (team == flag.getTeam()) + "; " + team.equals(flag.getTeam()) + (team.hashCode() == flag.getTeam().hashCode()) + "^ " + team.toString().equals(flag.getTeam().toString());
                        ...
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't `==` returning `true`?

Comment: Please stop explaining code and show your actual code. Right now I do not "trust" the `toString` implementation. And I do not trust `team` vs. `this.team` which can be different things.

Comment: Because the references aren't referring to the same object. That's what `==` returning false means, all else is irrelevant (and most likely an oversight on your part, a typo, or similar).

Comment: You should include the specific methods that are giving you issues. As of right now it's not enough to go off of.

Comment: `String a = new String("hello");` and `String b = new String("hello");`: `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` is true; `a.toString().equals(b.toString())` is true; `a == b` is false.

Comment: Why do you expect `flag.getTeam()` to return the same object as `team`?  The code that you've shown explains nothing.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I don't expect them to, I am testing if they are, and they look like they share addresses, so that's why I'm confused.

Comment: You should maybe read up on what the numbers after the `@` in the `toString` output mean: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29 (its not the memory address)

Comment: No, @LuaiGhunim you are mistaken.  The instance variables do _not_ refer to the same address in memory; and that's what the result of `==` is telling us.  The real question is why they give the same output for `toString`.  Without seeing what's going on in the `Team` class, and possibly also the `Flag` class, it's impossible to answer this.

Comment: Yes he had not posted the whole code and i guess he wants that two objects should be declared equal if some scaledDistance < 1 and @luk2305 you are right `==` work for both, coming from Haskell i had something else in mind btw deleted answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the misunderstanding is coming from how the `toString()` method is implemented. Calling `toString` on an object will produce a String [equivalent to the following value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29)

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The key point to realize is that while hashcode for an `Object` is [based on memory location](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()), hashcode for a `String` is based on the `String`'s [value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()). So it is possible to produce the same `toString()` output, with different `String` objects that have the same contents.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is that you are trying to compare objects. Two objects can have the same values, but they have different place in the memory. When you used == you compared the pointers (which have different address in memory) not the object values. To do so you should use .equals() as you did in the third line. 
The hashCode will be the same if the object were created in the same "way" (use the same class and fields, so hashCode equation gives the same value - which is correct). Summarizing, when you use == on two objects with the same values of atributes they are in fact two different objects with dfferent memory address.

Comment: *"when you use == on objects you get always false"* is incorrect. `Object something = ...; Object a = something; System.out.println(a == something);` prints `true`. As does `a == a` and `something == something`.

Comment: And it appears OP already understands the meaning of `==`.

Comment: I have rewrite last sentence in the more correct way. Let me know if you are still do not agree.